# Which one trove openstack is? a database as a service solution or a virtual machine image database?

Tags: database, cloud, openstack

I am a new user to openstack trove. As far as I found (from the process of creating datastore and database in trove) trove works like this: For each datastore instance there is a nova-compute image that this instance will be launch on that (and also a cinder storage assigned to this instance) Therefore there is not a centralized database which could be manage by openstack administrator. As far as I know there are two types of cloud database: 1)virtual machine image database and 2)dbaas. For dbaas it should not be like having a virtual machine instance per each database and database provisioning should be manageable by system administrator (not client). Therefore could somebody explain for me how trove works and how could we consider it dbaas and not virtual machine image database?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Trove is an openstack service that provides an API for creating a relational or non-relational database to a user. This database can be used within a deployed application. So in your terms it is a database as a service solution.

Trove provisions an instance from an image for a single tenant. This is not meant to be a centralized database for openstack.

To get more details about Trove 
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Trove

Comment: Does Trove supports elasticity? For example can I change the size of DB on the fly? Also does Trove supports self service provisioning?

Comment: Trove allows you to resize the memory of the instance and resize the volume independently. [trove cli doc](https://github.com/openstack/python-troveclient#id2) 

Trove provisions a nova instance and volume and setups it all up so you should never have to maintain the instance manually. You have the api to manage the instance database. Trove supports multiple datastore s (mysql/couchdb/mongo/etc).